# Applicative instance for Reader monad

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz, applicative

I thought that every monad in `scalaz` had also an `Applicative` instance. For example, I can use `ApplicativeBuilder` for `Option` like this:

```
scala> (1.some |@| 2.some) {_ + _}
res1: Option[Int] = Some(3)
```

Now I'd like to do the same with `Reader`:

```
scala> type IntReader[A] = Reader[Int, A]
defined type alias IntReader

scala> val r1: IntReader[Int] = Reader {x: Int => x + 1 }
r1: IntReader[Int] = Reader(<function1>)

scala> val r2: IntReader[Int] = Reader {x: Int => x + 2 }
r2: IntReader[Int] = Reader(<function1>)

scala> (r1 |@| r2) {_ + _}
<console>:64: error: value |@| is not a member of IntReader[Int]
          (r1 |@| r2) {_ + _}
```

Why doesn't this code above compile ?

Comment: Are you sure you've imported `scalaz.syntax.apply._`?

Comment: Oh, no. I will try, thank you.

Comment: @TravisBrown Yes, it is working with the import ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness: the `Applicative` instance is available with no imports:

```
scala> type IntReader[A] = scalaz.Reader[Int, A]
defined type alias IntReader

scala> scalaz.Applicative[IntReader]
res0: scalaz.Applicative[IntReader] = scalaz.KleisliInstances3$$anon$3@f979171
```

But if you want to use the `|@|` syntax you'll need to import `scalaz.syntax.apply._`:

```
scala> import scalaz.syntax.apply._
import scalaz.syntax.apply._

scala> val r1: IntReader[Int] = scalaz.Reader((x: Int) => x + 1)
r1: IntReader[Int] = Kleisli(<function1>)

scala> val r2: IntReader[Int] = scalaz.Reader((x: Int) => x + 2)
r2: IntReader[Int] = Kleisli(<function1>)

scala> (r1 |@| r2) { _ + _ }
res1: IntReader[Int] = Kleisli(<function1>)
```

This is because `|@|` isn't a method on `Reader`—it's provided by an `ApplyOps` enrichment class.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.